# Do you need to enable all of the IC's chip select lines to select an IC?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit

If there is an IC with multiple CS (chip select) lines, like the (old) MOS 6540 (for example):

[image: 6540 pinout]

Source: [cbmhardware.de](http://www.cbmhardware.de/show.php?r=14&id=77/MOS%206540%20ROM%20und%206550%20RAM)

*Warning: This pinout may not be 100% correct, please take a look at this website: [dasarodesigns.com](http://www.dasarodesigns.com/a/6540-rom-adapter-rev-1/)*

Is it correct that you need to enable **all** of the available CS lines to enable the chip (with *enable* I mean high for high-active **CS** and low for low-active **_CS** inputs)?

*Not meant to be a 6540-specific question!*

Comment: Something is wrong with the image.

Comment: @BenceKaulics Looks OK on my computer (even after refreshing site). Or are you referring to an error in the document? If so, please let us know, what is incorrect.

Comment: 1: Off topic. 2: How is this not directly answered in the datasheet right where you'd expect to find it!?

Comment: @OlinLathrop Read the comments below and you shall find the answers to your questions. :)

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/126279/why-do-74-series-ics-have-two-enable-pins

Comment: It is unusual that this has a VTC for being a shopping question.

Comment: This website seems to corroborate with that figure at least: http://www.amiga-stuff.com/hardware/6540.html

Comment: May be you can ask about it on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typically, yes. A chip is not selected unless *all* its chip select lines are activated. Sometimes the chip selects have different polarity, one is negated and the other is not.

This usually simplifies the chip select logic, and does no harm because if you only need one, you can tie the others to whatever level necessary.

Comment: Yeah.  If you had only one CS line you'd need to use a binary decoder to select one of N chips.  But with multiple lines and a  dash of cleverness/insight you can simply use "logic" in the printed circuit wires to do this.

Comment: @pipe, the answer to this question is specifics for each IC.  Every IC with multiple CS# lines which I've seen so far, had multiple features and each CS# would select a particular feature, or a combination of CS# lines would select a feature.  So, the right answer is "*There is no common behavior.  Read the datasheet.*", rather than "*Typically, yes.*"  On that note, -1 (no hard feelings).

Comment: The question itself lacks the link to the datasheet, which makes the question unclear.  Despite missing the datasheet, the question got promoted to hot network questions.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Here: [74138](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/74HC138.pdf). Now you have seen an IC with three CS-lines. Same goes for the ROMs I've seen, though I can't find good datasheet for them. Maybe you're talking about WE and OE, because I can't really think of something called a "chip select" unless it actually selects the whole chip instead of a particular function.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Something has to be done about the hot network question list in general, though.

Comment: the datasheet of the 6540 has its 40th anniversary. should go to retrocomputing SE. here is as much as I could find: http://www.amiga-stuff.com/hardware/6540.html, including the reasoning for having five chip selects: *mask options provide user specification of chip select equations, allowing addressing anywhere within a 65K memory space without external decode circuitry*

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes the answer is yes. But this is a chip design specific thing and requires that you look at each part's data sheet. There is NO general answer for this.

Comment: Sure true, unfortunately the datasheet for (e.g.) the 6540 is not available (or at least I haven't found it..).

Comment: @RhinoDevel - Then change your question to be specific about that one chip if that is what you are having problems with. You asked a broad question with only vague reference to one chip so you get a broad answer.

Comment: No, that's fine. This was meant to be a "newbie" question. :-)

Comment: Don't just pass it off. If you want to move from "newbie" where you learn something valuable then stop it. My point stands!!

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to be rude (I am no native english speaker). I get your point, but I wanted to know, if this is something "everybody" knows about, that I just missed (search engine did not help). Maybe I will ask another 6540 specific question. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

I can't find a datasheet for the 6540 online anywhere, but I did come across a design for an adaptor that allows you to replace it with a different ROM such as a 2716:

http://www.dasarodesigns.com/product/6540-rom-adapter-rev-1/

In the accompanying text it states:

> 2) The 6540 has five chip select lines. CS3, CS4, and CS5 are active low meaning that they must be held low (+0v) for the chip to be on (its data lines to be low impedance). CS1 and CS2 are active high, meaning that they are must be high (+5v) for the chip to be on.

As this information appears to have been used to produce a working design it's likely to be correct.

As others have stated, it's important to check the datasheet for the exact answer but certainly in my experience it's usual to have to activate all the chip select lines in order to enable a device.